# how to append a variable to id of radio button in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a variable that holds a value and i want to pass this variable as the id of a radio button but when i aspect the element, the value of the id in the radio button is num not 1.

```
 var num=1; 
  $("ol").append("<li> <input type='radio' id=num />  <textarea  rows='2' cols='3'>  </textarea>  <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='remove'><img class='delete' src='images/cross.png' width='16' height='16' border='0'></a></li>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean to do this:

```
var num = 1; 
$("ol").append("<li> <input type='radio' id='" + num + "' /> ... ");
```

Comment: should also quote html attribute values...not required when no spaces or special characters involved but is a best practice

Comment: True. However, the ID attribute must not contain any space character. It can contain punctuation, but that doesn't work well if you're using it in CSS selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this is more jQuery

```js
var num = 1;
$("ol").append("<li />").append(
  $("<input />", {
    "type": "radio",
    "id": num
  }).append(
    $("<textarea/>", {
      "rows": 2,
      "cols": 3
    })
  ).append(
    $("<a/>", {
      "href": "javascript: void(0)",
      "class": "remove"
    }).append(
      $("<img/>", {
        "class": "delete",
        "src": "images/cross.png",
        "width": 16,
        "height": 16,
        "border": 0
      })
    )
  )
)
```